# Microsoft Azure Linux Virtual Machine SSH Public-private Keys Authentication for multiple users

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ssh-keys

I understand that one could connect to a Virtual Server by either SSH Public-private Keys Authentication OR by merely using a username and password.

If SSH Public-private Keys Authentication type is used and i decide to give another user access to the server, must I share my private key with him or he can create his own private key that would still work with the public key on the Virtual Machine?

Comment: Usually they would generate their own key pair and then you'd add their public key to the server.

Comment: Great! I guess that can be done from the Azure Portal

Comment: That one I actually don't know :) I don't really work with VMs.

Answer (score 1):

For the SSH key, the public key and the private key are one to one. So the first, you can use the same private key to access the VM from different on-premise machines via the same user.

And second, if you want to use the same public key for different users, then you need to share the public key with different users in the VM by setting the `authorized_keys` file. It means you need to add the `authorized_keys` file in each users' `/home/user/.ssh` path.

**Update:**

Here is the screenshot that adds or updates the user with the public SSH key for the existing VM:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you give details on how to add their public key to existing Azure Linux Virtual Machine using the Azure Portal?

Comment: Thank you Charles. I will try that out.